# Massive Rep Loss due user deletion

Tags: support

I had a massive 208 reputation loss today. It seems like a user was deleted? Any idea what happened here? Is this normal to lose so much rep score on an event like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there was a user account deleted - I don't know exactly why, but as I lost about 1800 across the network, it must have been someone fairly prolific with upvotes.

As I understand it, normally when an account is deleted, recent votes are removed, but older votes are kept, so I assume these were all in the recent category (3 or 6 months I think)

Pretty rare - I haven't encountered one this big before.

Comment: Yeah, Video Production was also impacted and had a question about it.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328642/massive-user-removal-in-one-night) meta post covers more (not much more) from SE on the subject.

Comment: I think the old/new votes you're thinking of is for when *posts* are deleted, not accounts - it's [60 days (plus a minimum score of +3)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/). For account deletions, the default behavior is actually that all votes are removed except in special cases. So, if a user creates a profile on a site, votes a handful of times and then decides to delete the profile a year later, those votes are removed.